# Choose an image from gallery and show it using an ImageView

Tags: android, image, android-intent, onclick, gallery

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD = 1;
String img_Decodable_Str;


ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD);

        }
    });}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            img_Decodable_Str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(img_Decodable_Str));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hey pick your image first",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went embrassing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}}
```

I have an **ImageView**. If the user clicks on the **ImageView** he will be able to add an image of his choice to it. When i click on the **ImageView** I'm redirected to gallery but when i choose an image, that image isn't showing in the **ImageView**. where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the short term, replace:

```
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        // Get the cursor
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        img_Decodable_Str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
        // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                .decodeFile(img_Decodable_Str));
```

with:

```
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
```

Later, use an image-loading library, such as Picasso or Glide, as `setImageURI()` loads the image on the main application thread, which will freeze your UI for as long as that work takes.